# Aggregate error when trying to use many to many table with sequelize

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

I'm getting this error:

```
AggregateError: aggregate error
    at Promise.try.then
    ...
```

when trying to setup a many to many table in sequelize with this code:

```
let _document
db.document.create(payload, { include: ['documentAttributes', 'documentChildren'] })
  .then(document => {
    _document = document
    const promises = []

    // Add tags if there are any
    if (req.body.tags) {
      req.body.tags.forEach(tag => {
        promises.push(db.tag.findOrCreate({ where: { key: tag.key } }))
      })
    }

    return Promise.all(promises)
  })
  .then(tags => {
    if (tags.length > 0) {
      const allTags = tags.map(tag => tag[0])
      return _document.setTags(allTags) // THIS LINE CAUSES THE ISSUE
    }
```

`document.js` model:

```
'use strict'

module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const document = sequelize.define('document', {
    id: {
      allowNull: false,
      primaryKey: true,
      type: DataTypes.UUID,
      defaultValue: DataTypes.UUIDV4
    },
    ...
    lastUpdatedBy: {
      allowNull: false,
      type: DataTypes.UUID
    }
  },
  {
    updatedAt: 'lastUpdatedAt'
  })
  document.associate = function (models) {
    document.hasMany(models.documentAttribute)
    document.hasMany(models.documentChildren)
    document.belongsToMany(models.tag, { through: 'documentTags' })
  }
  return document
}
```

`tag.js` model:

```
'use strict'
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const tag = sequelize.define('tag', {
    id: {
      allowNull: false,
      primaryKey: true,
      type: DataTypes.UUID,
      defaultValue: DataTypes.UUIDV4
    },
    key: {
      allowNull: false,
      type: DataTypes.STRING
    },
    value: {
      allowNull: false,
      type: DataTypes.STRING
    },
    lastUpdatedBy: {
      allowNull: false,
      type: DataTypes.UUID
    }
  },
  {
    updatedAt: 'lastUpdatedAt'
  })
  tag.associate = function (models) {
    tag.belongsToMany(models.document, { through: 'documentTags' })
  }
  return tag
}
```

`documenttags.js` model:

```
'use strict'
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const documentTags = sequelize.define('documentTags', {
    id: {
      allowNull: false,
      primaryKey: true,
      type: DataTypes.UUID,
      defaultValue: DataTypes.UUIDV4
    },
    documentId: {
      allowNull: false,
      type: DataTypes.UUID
    },
    tagId: {
      allowNull: false,
      type: DataTypes.UUID
    },
    lastUpdatedBy: {
      allowNull: false,
      type: DataTypes.UUID
    }
  },
  {
    updatedAt: 'lastUpdatedAt'
  })
  documentTags.associate = function (models) {
    // associations can be defined here
  }
  return documentTags
}
```

Comment: At a glance the code seems fine; are you sure the `tag.key` is never undefined?

Comment: Yep i just double checked by logging `tag.key` and it's always a string.

Comment: Looks like AggregateError is really not referring to like a SQL/db aggregation, its just an array-like of errors; http://docs.sequelizejs.com/class/lib/model.js~Model.html - they say that means validation is failing. Can you check for more details on the error?

Comment: I just updated my question. It wasn't the creating of the tags that was causing an issue it was using `setTags` that was causing the issue.

Comment: @Catalyst From that link i'm not following how I can check the validation errors. Do you know how I can do that?

Comment: looks like its bluebird underneath -http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/aggregateerror.html - so you can do something like `error.forEach(e => console.log(e))`

Comment: Ok that helps a lot. Gives me errors like this `e =  { SequelizeBulkRecordError: notNull Violation: documentTags.lastUpdatedBy cannot be null`. When using sequelize's dynamic `set<model>` (in my case `setTags` method, how can I add values to the many to many table (in my case the `documentTags` table?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191859/discussion-between-catalyst-and-catfish).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After reviewing the docs and discussing in the chat. The `through` property is necessary to set extra properties on the many-to-many table. 
http://docs.sequelizejs.com/class/lib/associations/belongs-to-many.js~BelongsToMany.html

```
return _document.setTags(allTags, { through: { lastUpdatedBy: tag.lastUpdatedBy }})
```